# UWP - Image Uri in Application Folder

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm having a little issue here in showing images.

So when I'm trying to load images from XAML, I can use a relative uri to the image source like this :

```
<Image Source="/Assets/image.jpg" />
```

But if I try to change the image source programatically from code behind, I always get an exception and I'm sure it's because of the false Uri. I tried something like this :

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/image.jpg"));
```

Am I doing it wrong? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To access files stored inside the application package, but from code where there is no inferred root authority, you need to specify the ms-appx: scheme :

So in your case it will be something like :

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = 
                     new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///[project-name]/Assets/image.jpg"));
```

Read this documentation for more details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: project must be search from the package root, you need 3 / at the begining: "ms-appx:///[project-name]/Assets/image.jpg"

Comment: I'm getting a `System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized` when using an `ms-appx:///` prefix

Comment: You need to also set the build action of the image file to Content and set copy to output directory to either Copy Always or Copy If Newer.

Answer (score 40):

You can also use it with BaseUri.

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "/Assets/image.jpg"));
```

Assets is a folder name and you can change it with your any custom folder name :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe WPF is more forgiving and paths like "Assets/image.png" are possible.  If you are writing a UWA (win 10) app then you need to use the "ms-appx" URI's.

My experience is "ms-appx:///Assets/image.png" works fine.

Yes, three "/"s (!) and no need for the name of the app in the path.

Answer (score -4):

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/images/logo.png"));
```

Answer (score -5):

Just use it like this

```
<Image Source="Assets/image.jpg" />
```