# How can I change image.source with C# when creating a UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm developing my first Windows 10 UWP app. I have an image. This is its XAML code:

```
<Image x:Name="image" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Height="50" 
               Margin="280,0,0,25" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
               Width="50" 
               Source="Assets/Five.png"/>
```

And im trying to change image.source with this code:

```
        private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage One = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/One.png"));
        BitmapImage Two = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Two.png"));
        BitmapImage Three = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Three.png"));
        BitmapImage Four = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Four.png"));
        BitmapImage Five = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Five.png"));

        if (slider.Value == 1)
        {
            image.Source = One;
        }
        else if (slider.Value == 2)
        {
            image.Source = Two;
        }
        else if (slider.Value == 3)
        {
            image.Source = Three;
        }
        else if (slider.Value == 4)
        {
            image.Source = Four;
        }
        else if (slider.Value == 5)
        {
            image.Source = Five;
        }
    }
```

But when I compile the code I get this error pointing to the variable declaration:

> UriFormatException was unhandled by user code

Answer (score 11):

> Windows Runtime APIs do not support URIs of type **UriKind.Relative**, so you typically use the signature that infers the **UriKind** and make sure you've specified a valid absolute URI including the scheme and authority.

To access files stored inside the application package, but from code where there is no inferred root authority, specify the **ms-appx:** scheme like following:

```
BitmapImage One = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/One.png"));
```

For more info, please see [How to load file resources (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx) and [URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj655406.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the additional UriKind parameter for each of your URI objects, so that they are defined as Relative e.g.

```
new Uri("Assets/One.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. This however has caused ArgumentsException was unhandled by user code. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314799/uwp-image-uri-in-application-folder)

Comment: Hi, Wasn't really of much use. Thanks anyway.