# Control doesn't display bound content until xaml changes in debug

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I'm trying to make a custom control for an app I'm making, that has a textblock and an image that can be changed in code with bindings.  So far, it mostly works, once I get past one little hitch: when I go to debug the app, initially the image doesn't show on the control, but when I go into the control's template and change remove "Template" from "TemplateBinding", wait a few seconds, and then put it back, the image suddenly pops up on the control.  Here's my code.

Template:

```
<Style TargetType="local:SoundButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SoundButton">
                <Grid Background="#303030" Padding="10,10,10,10">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    <Image x:Name="PlayingImg" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="60,60,0,0" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Control Class:

```
public sealed class SoundButton : Button
{
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PathProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty PathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(string), typeof(SoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FileNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty FileNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FileName", typeof(string), typeof(SoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(SoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(SoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private MediaElement Media = null;

    public SoundButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(SoundButton);
    }

    public async void LoadSound()
    {
        Media = new MediaElement();
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
        Media.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), file.ContentType);
        Media.MediaEnded += Stopped;
    }

    private void Stopped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stop();
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        Media.Stop();
        ImageSource = "Assets\\Images\\Play.png";
    }

    protected override void OnTapped(TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Media == null)
        {
            LoadSound();
        }
        base.OnTapped(e);
        if (Media.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            Stop();
        else
        {
            Media.Play();
            ImageSource = "Assets\\Images\\Stop.png";
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that it wouldn't actually show the image unless I did this (demonstrated on TextBlock value, which was having the same problem before):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bg6npa6ucqoii2w/ControlXamlUpdate.mp4?dl=0

While I was debugging.  I really don't understand why this is this way.  There is very little documentation out there, that I could find, in the way of custom controls.  Why isn't the image showing up immediately on run?  And why does changing the template like that make it work suddenly?

Comment: Is `ImageSource`  a string or an int? Your dep prop declaration has both. Wouldn't it ordinarily be [an `ImageSource` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagesource)?

Comment: It's a string, because I'm replacing what would normally be the `Source` string value in the Xaml layout of an `Image` element, as shown in the template.  It works just fine as it is, when I do that edit and undo while debugging.  In my search for binding an `Image` source, nothing mentioned `ImageSource`.

Comment: "It works just fine as it is". OK, why are you here asking for help?

Comment: You're not addressing the issue.  You brought up a part of the code that is working just fine.  The problem is NEITHER the image NOR the textblock show up unless I do that trick while debugging.

Comment: There is exactly one thing wrong in the code you posted: The propertyType parameter for all of your `string` dependency properties is `typeof(int)`. Your reason for not fixing it is that, in light of your knowledge of the cause of your issue (zero, by your account), you're not convinced that it's relevant. I suggest you fix that and then see where you are. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: (oops -- a second thing wrong: `Media.CurrentState` is an enum; converting it to a string for comparison is not good practice. But that can't be the issue here.).

Comment: Now that you word it that way, yes, that was stupid of me.  I see that's what you were talking about in the first comment, but you brought up the `ImageSource` type and I didn't see anything else anymore.  However, that only fixed the TextBlock.  I still have to do that trick for the `Image` source.  Like I mentioned before, I never saw anything about `ImageSource` before, if there's a better way to bind that value, I'm all ears.  And thanks for the note about `CurrentState`.  I changed that too.

Comment: The [`Image.Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the `Image` in your XAML is of type `ImageSource`, which is a base class of [`BitmapImage` and others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage). So if you change the type of your `ImageSource` to `ImageSource`, you'd assign `this.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pathString));`If your image is a resource, [this answer may help with that part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314882/424129).

Comment: If you give `Image.Source` a literal string in the XAML attribute, a TypeConverter will silently step in and create an appropriate image object. I don't think that's going to happen here, but I'm on Win7 at work and can't test UWP stuff.

Comment: Ohhh, that might explain why it suddenly was working when I changed the template.  It was probably invoking that type converter.  Changed everything to ImageSource and it worked fine.  Now I need to figure out how to add event listeners, since the image doesn't change back to the "play" icon when the media has ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to clarify out of the comments that Ed made, my first problem was not matching the `typeof` in the `DependencyProperty` registration to the type of the actual property (that solved the `TextBlock` binding issue).  My second was not understanding that the `Source` value of `Image` was an `ImageSource`, not a string, therefore making my string assignments in code meaningless.  Created two static `ImageSource` values for those two images I wanted in the buttons, and changed the assignments to use those, and that works perfectly now, too.  Thanks Ed!