# The UWP application does not send an image

Tags: c#, image, uwp

The UWP application does not display an image so I do not.
Here is my code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem Header="Write">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel Loaded="WriteStackPanel_Loaded" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="WriteText_1"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            Text="text 1"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="WriteText_2"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            Text="text 2"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <Grid Height="70" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="Assets\AppData\About\Checks\write_image_1.png" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

I also did the following
1) Build action is set to content.

2) And try to set always **copy to output directory" in your image properties.
As was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095187/uwp-app-does-not-show-image).
It does not go in the application, but in the constructor in Visual Studio everything is there.
[Screen folder Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxe2.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the Assets folder structure in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the screenshot of your Assets folder and it indeed seems there is no `write_image_1.png` image in the `Assets\AppData\About\Checks` folder, there is only a `text_write.txt` file.

If the image is in this folder (in file explorer), it is probably just not included. Click the **Show all files** button in the top toolbar of the Solution Explorer to display all files. Then right-click the image file and select **Include In Project**.

Comment: I apologize. I originally posted the wrong screenshot. The folder has all the files you need. I re-uploaded the screenshot

Comment: Could you please upload a [mcve] for us to diagnose this issue?